# Major Ticks and Minor Ticks using Dygraphs

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am working with Dygraphs. I need to have a graph with a background of a grid that has major ticks in dark blue color and minor ticks in light blue color. There should be 1 major tick after every 4 minor ticks. I am looking for an effect similar to the picture shown below.

[image]

Picture courtsey :Stack overflow

I have spent a lot of time but have not been able to understand how to do it. Any lead in this direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using an [`underlayCallback`](http://dygraphs.com/tests/highlighted-region.html). Something like:

```
var g = new Dygraph(div, data,
    {
      underlayCallback: function(canvas, area, g) {
        for (const tick of majorTicks) {
          const x = g.toDomCoordsX(tick);
          canvas.fillRect(x, area.y, x, area.h);
        }
      }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much danvk. This is perfect.

Comment: I'm using ticker function to generate gridlines and wondering if the underlayCallback still works in this case @dvank